# Laravel route sometimes is firing another one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this "general" route in Laravel5 and it's for AngularJS (all get requests redirect to home which contains the HTML where's included angularJS):

```
Route::get( '{path?}', function() {

    return view( 'home' );

})->where( 'path', '.+' );
```

And before this there's the one of API (ajax):

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'api' ], function() {

    Route::resource( 'user', 'UserController' );

});
```

So first there's "API" and after "angular". The problem is that often when I call the page *api/SOMETHING* is firing the second route (AngularJS) with the html response instead of the real one (the one of the resource, a JSON), so I wrote this little "hack":

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...
Route::get( '{path?}', function(Request $request) {

    if ( $request->is( 'api/*') )
        return redirect( $request->fullUrl() );

    return view( 'home' );

})->where( 'path', '.+' );
```

Now the problem is solved at 95%, but often it happens again only at the first load.

Any idea? Middleware / Before?

Comment: what you have to notice about routes is the ordering is important, as it you have `domain/admin/{path?}` then have `domain/admin/login`, then goto domain/admin/login in your browser the first route will always catch it and not get to the required route?  So try running `php artisan route:list`to see your routes and the output to see if any will effect this

Comment: The problem is that if I go to /api/something I except a JSON and it works at 95% of times, but the other 5% the route {path?} is invoked. Weird.

Comment: you abel to post yoru complete route file as you have it / want it and also if possible run php artisan route:list as well, jus might be easier to read as one whole route file rather than split up like that :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, it sounds like you're assuming that once Laravel enters a route group it is "stuck" in that route group. However, if no routes are matched within the group, Laravel will "continue" on down the list of registered routes all the way down to your catchall `{path?}` route.

Maybe make a catchall route in your `api` route group?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {

    // API routes go here here

    Route::get('{path}', function() {
        // I believe this is the right way to make a JSON response in Laravel 5
        return response()->json(['error' => 'endpoint not found']);
    })->where('path', '.*');

});
```